# What happens if I make an existing custom field Unique and there are already duplicate values?

Tags: unique-field

If I have an existing custom field where there are some duplicate values across records, but which should ideally be a unique key, is it possible to make it unique? If so, what happens to the existing records with duplicate values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be allowed to complete the modification. All values must already be unique or null before imposing a unique index. You'll get an error like the following:

```
Error: Duplicate value(s) found when building unique index, example: ...
```

You must first *clean up* the duplicate values before you'll be allowed to make an index.

Comment: Well sheeeit.  If some of those records are leads that have already been converted then I'm just out of luck, huh?

Comment: There's a jam, for sure. Probably would involve deleting those old leads, or perhaps making a new field, making it unique, then using the data loader to copy what values you can.